# django-money form field in unit test

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I am using [django-money](https://github.com/django-money/django-money) and I have a money field (`value = MoneyField(…)`) I want to test in a model form. This is the code:

```
def test_post_valid(self):
    data = {'value': Money('99.99', currency='GBP'), }
    response = self.client.post(url, data)
```

I get an error in the form parsing code stating:

```
(Pdb++) form.errors                                                             
{u'value': [u'This field is required.']}
```

What is the correct format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`django-money` does a hack with their `MoneyField`, which doesn't translate to a simple HTML form field, and instead produces two HTML form fields for the value and the currency code.

You have to pass `value` of type `Decimal` (or any value that can be coerced to `Decimal`) and `value_currency` of the 3-character currency code (`ChoiceField` of country codes).

```
def test_post_valid(self):
    data = {'value_0': '99.99', 'value_1': 'GBP' }
    response = self.client.post(url, data)
```

Comment: You can also check out django-money's test suite to see more working tests.

https://github.com/django-money/django-money/blob/master/tests/test_form.py

Comment: Between @HåkenLid and yourself, I got it. You need `data = {'value_0': '99.99', 'value_1': 'GBP' }`.

Comment: Ah, then they might have changed their API fairly recently (0.10 maybe), which sucks because it will break our code and I don't see any mention of it in their documentation.  In the version that we have, we have to pass the original name of the field for the numeric value, then name of the field + "_currency" for the currency code. Good to know, but strange that I have to learn it here.